# Changing cell colors in vba if sum on each row is not correct

Tags: vba, excel

I am a video person, and only a beginner excel wiz, so this current challenge has me in an area where i have less experience than most in the forum. I need to build a macro which i can install on less savvy user's excel toolbars to do some data checking for me.

I have excel documents with 3 relevant columns and up to 999 rows. Each row in the worksheet represents a video shot.

Col D is a "frame in" value (an integer from 1 to 999,999)
Col E is a "frame out" value (also an integer from 1 to 999,999)
Col F is a "duration" value which SHOULD be (Col E - Col D + 1)

I have a VBA script (that i Frankenstein-ed together from code on this site) which checks for things in other columns (A, B, C) related to shotname length, etc.

Now I want to call a new function which will color the duration column (col F) cell background  if there is an error in the worksheet and the duration of the shot is longer or shorter than the in/out values would suggest. (and also perhaps if the "frame out" of one shot is not equal to the "frame in" of the next row (minus one).

I have searched the site exhaustively, but can't seem to locate a function which loops through my range of cells and does math to the ROWS individually, instead of totalling the COLS.

Any pointers would be most helpful. I've resisted asking a question because i'm stubborn and want to do it myself, but i'm running out of time. I have obviously figured out how to do it with formulas, but I can't easily train others on my team to do the formulas.

Jamie

In response to the request below, there is a function i am using to see if shot names in Col A are unique... sorry if the formatting is a little off!

```
Private Sub CntUniqueShotNamesRowA()

'This routine enumerates the number of unique values in the Shot Names Column (a).
'it returns the number of unique items in the range of (a:a)

Dim Uni As Collection, cl As Range, LpRange As Range

Dim clswfrm As Range, clswcst As Range, myRng As Range
Dim TotUni As Long
Set myRng = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).[a:a] 'sheet/range defined here

On Error Resume Next
Set clswfrm = myRng.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
Set clswcst = myRng.SpecialCells(xlConstants)
Set myRng = Nothing 'free up memory
On Error GoTo 0

If clswfrm Is Nothing And clswcst Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No Unique Cells? (or no content?)"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Not clswfrm Is Nothing And Not clswcst Is Nothing Then
    Set LpRange = Union(clswcst, clswfrm)
ElseIf clswfrm Is Nothing Then Set LpRange = clswcst
Else: Set LpRange = clswfrm
End If

Set clswfrm = Nothing: Set clswcst = Nothing 'Free up memory
Set Uni = New Collection

On Error Resume Next
For Each cl In LpRange
    Uni.Add cl.Value, CStr(cl.Value) 'assign unique key string
Next cl
On Error GoTo 0

Set LpRange = Nothing 'free up memory
TotUni = Uni.Count
Set Uni = Nothing ''free up memory
MsgBox "There are " & TotUni & " unique shot names in Row A."
End Sub
```

Here is my pseudocoded attempt to make this work.... apologies to any who are confused by my   comments.

```
Sub FlagBadShotDurations()

' This routine will enumerate the length of each shot from the 
' in and out frames in Col D and Col E.
' it will then compare with the listed duration in col F.
' if F is not matching the calculated value it will 
' flag the cell with a yellow BG

'set range and counter
Dim myRng As Range
Dim ShotCount As Long

'set places to do formula work
Dim FrameIn As Long
Dim FrameOut As Long
Dim calculatedDuration As Long
Dim Duration As Long

'count problem shots
Dim TotalIssues As Long


Set myRng = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).[f:f] 'sheet/range defined here
Set ShotCount = 1

For Each ShotCount In myRng
    'Set FrameIn as the cell value for the D column
    'Set FrameOut as the cell value for the E column
    'Set Duration as the cell value for the F column

    ' if FrameOut - FrameIn +1 <> Duration then
    'set TotalIssues = TotalIssues + 1
    'set BG color of Duration Cell to Yellow.

Next ShotCount

If TotalIssues > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Enumerated Durations from Ins and Outs and marked" & TotalIssues & "problems"
Else
    MsgBox "Enumerated Durations from Ins and Outs and found no problems"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post some of the A,B,C code that you've already created?  It'll be easier to help get a specific, correct answer.

Comment: I'm not convinced VBA is the best solution. Why can't you just use Conditional Formatting, using the formula you've already figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my completed function and it works!

```
Private Sub FlagBadShotDurations()
' This routine will enumerate the length of each shot from the in and out frames in Col D and Col E.
' it will then compare with the listed duration in col F.
' if F is not matching the calculated value it will flag the cell with a yellow BG

'set range and counter
Dim rng As Range

'set places to do formula work
Dim FrameIn As Long
Dim FrameOut As Long
Dim Duration As Long

'count problem shots
Dim TotalIssues As Long
TotalIssues = 0

'define last used row
Dim lastRow As Long

'evaluate last row
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

'set counter
Dim myCurrentRow As Long
myCurrentRow = 1

'Set rng = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).[d:f]
Set rng = Range("D1:D" & lastRow)

For Each c In rng.Cells
    'Set FrameIn as the cell value for the D column
    FrameIn = Range("D" & myCurrentRow).Value

    'Set FrameOut as the cell value for the E column
    FrameOut = Range("E" & myCurrentRow).Value

    'Set Duration as the cell value for the F column
    Duration = Range("F" & myCurrentRow).Value

    If (FrameOut - FrameIn + 1) <> Duration Then
       'note incidence of problem
       TotalIssues = TotalIssues + 1
       'set BG color of Duration Cell to Yellow
       Range("F" & myCurrentRow).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 250, 85)
    Else
       Range("F" & myCurrentRow).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

    myCurrentRow = myCurrentRow + 1

Next

If TotalIssues > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Checked all Shot Durations by calculating correct durations from shot Ins and Outs." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Found and marked " & TotalIssues & " problem(s) in yellow"
Else
    MsgBox "Found no problems with shot durations."
End If

End Sub
```